# Could we see a user's rep in the popup appearing when clicking on an avatar

Tags: feature-request, reputation, chat

In the chat, when I click on someone's avatar, there pops up a small box displaying some info from the chat profile, and links to the chat profile, the parent site's profile, and the rooms that user is in. Can you please add the user's rep on the parent site to that info?

Rep is what holds SO together. We judge users by their rep. In the chat, either I know the users talking because they are regulars, or I look up their profile, mostly to know about their rep.
Also, I often see new users pop into the room which do not say anything. Often they are new users that can't talk yet and seem to come in just to listen. When I wonder whether they are allowed to talk, I always need to go to the parent site's profile to look up their rep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the rep in the tooltip on the user name on that same popup:

[image: picture showing how you can do it, with freehand circles]

Comment: You're a genius!

Comment: Well, still not 100% intuitive, will be nice to have the number someplace else, especially for mobile users who can't see tooltips.